# Gson Expose not working in subclass containing has a relationship

Tags: java, gson

I am attempting to serialize a inheritance object using Gson.

For e.g

```
        Class A {
        @Expose
        Integer id;
        } 

        class B extends A{
        @Expose
        Integer nos;
        @Expose
        C c;
        }

        Class C {
        @Expose
        Integer track;
        }

    B b = new B();
    C c = new C();
    c.setTrack(2);

    b.setNos(21);
    b.setC(c);

A a = (A)b;
a.setId(1);
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();

System.out.println(gson.toJson(b));
```

I want object c to be serialized with B object but unfortunately its coming as null while serializing object b ;

Please help me to sort this out

Comment: you should get `ClassCastException` when upcasting `a` to `B` : `B b = (B) a;`

Comment: yeah correcting the question give me a min

Comment: updated the question pls check let me know what i can do in this case with expose annotation i m trying to implement expose with hibernate entites so that i need not to write any other pojos for my services

Comment: i run your example and get : `{"nos":21,"c":{},"id":1}`

Comment: C is getting null is there is any reason for this. becoz whats happening with me is i have a generic class which is called task and its further categorized into 6 type of different task. Since i m using hibernate i cannot directly convert this object due to cyclic dependency. hence thought of using expose annonation. I m geeting task object and i m able to downcast it into its type but problem here is while downcasting it gives all superclass field value as well as sub class field value but subclass object field value is coming as null. I dont understand why

Comment: c is not null. it just has track not set. i forgot to annotate track with `@expose`. when i did it, i get : `{"nos":21,"c":{"track":2},"id":1}`

Comment: gson check object runtime type `src.getClass()`: `public String toJson(Object src) {
    if (src == null) {
      return toJson(JsonNull.INSTANCE);
    }
    return toJson(src, src.getClass());
  }`

Comment: see i cant be able to generate a scenario and my actual code is too large for the explanation but in case of database we can be able to downcast the superclass object to subclass object directly which polymorphic relationship between tables using pojos. i cannot write in plain java code